# Paddin new axis in 3d matrix returns error

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

What I need to do is to extend a 2D matrix to 3D and fill the 3rd axis with an arbitrary number of zero. The error returned is:

> all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the
> array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0
> dimension(s)

What should I correct?

```
import numpy as np

kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9
kernel = kernel[..., None]
print(type(kernel))

print(np.shape(kernel))
print(kernel)

i = 1
for i in range(27):
    np.append(kernel, 0, axis = 2)

print(kernel)
```

Comment: Don't use `np.append`, especially not without acually reading its docs.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What should I use instead of np.append()?*

Use `concatenate()`:

```
import numpy as np

kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9
kernel = kernel[..., None]
print(type(kernel))

print(np.shape(kernel))
print(kernel)
print('-----------------------------')

append_values = np.zeros((3,3))
append_values = append_values[..., None]
i = 1
for i in range(2):
    kernel = np.concatenate((kernel, append_values), axis=2)

print(kernel.shape)
print(kernel)
```

But best generate the `append_values` array already with the required shape in the third dimension to avoid looping:

```
append_values = np.zeros((3,3,2)) # or (3,3,27)
kernel = np.concatenate((kernel, append_values), axis=2)
print(kernel.shape)
print(kernel)
```

Comment: Using `np.concatenate` in a loop isn't any better.  ``np.append` is just a 2 array way of calling `np.append`.

Comment: I was just on the way to extend my answer with a version without a loop ... see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Everything works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output and error - full error, not just a piece!

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(3, 3, 1)
...

In [94]: np.append(kernel, 0, axis = 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [94], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.append(kernel, 0, axis = 2)

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in append(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:4817, in append(arr, values, axis)
   4815     values = ravel(values)
   4816     axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 4817 return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

As your `shape` shows `kernel` is 3d (3,3,1).  `np.append` takes the scalar 0, and makes an array, `np.array(0)`, and calls `concatenate`.  `concatenate`, if you take time to read its docs, requires matching numbers of dimensions.

But my main beef with your code was that you used `np.append` without capturing the result.  Again, if you take time to read the docs, you'll realize that `np.append` does not work in-place.  It does NOT modify `kernel`.  When it works, it returns a new array.  And doing that repeatedly in a loop is inefficient.

It looks like you took the list append model, applied it without much thought, to arrays.  That's not how to code `numpy`.

As the other answer shows, doing one `concatenate` with a (3,3,27) array of 0s is the way to go if you want to make a (3,3,28) array.

Alternatively make a (3,3,28) array of 0s, and copy the one (3,3,1) array to the appropriate column.